# Creating XSLT dynamic twitter bootstrap

Tags: xslt, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap, counter, web-deployment

I am having a slight problem with making a twitter bootstrap dynamic in XSLT. I don't even know if what I am doing is possible as the variables in XSLT are not changeable. Here is my code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="category">

<div class="accordion-heading">
  <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#accordion2" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  </a>
</div>
```

Basically, for each category, I need a new href to be created. Right now, it is set to collapseOne. I have tried a number of things such as position() to try to make this dynamic, but I cannot figure it out. Any input would be appreciated. If clarification or more code is required, please say so. I am new to posting on this forum. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The standard XSLT function [`generate-id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id) was created having in mind exactly this class of use-case scenarios.**